# Regex to restrict characters other than numbers, - and

Tags: regex

This is my regex which restricts any characters other than numbers -(minus) and .(dot)
Regex is as follows

```
(?!^-)[^0-9\.]
```

which allows - (minus) only at the start, But i would like to know If i can allow .(dot) only once and restrict the user to type the next .(dot)

My code

```
oninput => "this.value = this.value.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9\.]/g,'')"
```

Comment: Are you using any framework? Can you share a working code demo (codepen, stackblitz)?

Comment: `this.value.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9\.]/g,'')` makes for a garbage user experience. What happens when they have to delete something in the middle of the text or enter something new in the middle of text. In fact, any interaction which is not at the end of the line will be subpar.

Comment: Yes I'm using a internal framework. Don't have a codepen handy :(

Comment: Yes MonkeyZues, I agree Its not a good UX. But this is a bit sensitive field. So there is a strict validation on this field.

Comment: If the first paragraph of my answer accurately describes what you are trying to do I think your question would be much clearer if you were to begin it with a similar statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to allow:

- Optional leading minus (`-?`)
- At least one digit (`\d+`)
- Optional suffix: a dot, followed by at least one digit (`\.\d+`)

An appropriate regex is:

```
^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: I'm trying negate this expression. I added regex check on user input to the text field. I would like to restrict the user to enter the dot only once

Comment: Regarding the pattern, if you want to allow the dot exactly once you can make the suffix mandatory: `^-?\d+\.\d+$`. Do you want to match the entire input or just part of it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hodbn. I want to match the entire input. On every key stroke the user inputs i want to make sure there is only .(dot) in the input box

Comment: Then I'd suggest you use `/^-?\d+\.\d+$/.test(this.value)`.

Comment: I tried this, But didn't get approval :(  I completely need to restrict the user to enter

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problem? What exactly are you trying to restrict?

Comment: Lets say user enters 11.2.33   the input box should restrict the second dot. It should be displayed like 11.233.   so on input I have regex check.    So that's why I added a negated Regex.   this.value.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9\.]/g,' ').   Example: When ever user inputs an alphabet I'm replacing it with empty string.

Comment: Assuming the user appends characters, you can find the first match and drop everything else: `this.value = this.value.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)`.

Comment: Thanks @hodbn , Finally I'm to resolve the issue. I used "match" and this is the regex i used    `^-?((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+))$`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the user is to be restricted to entering the string representation of an integer or float (possibly negative), and that restrictions are to be imposed on a character-to-character basis. You therefore need a sequence of dynamically-constructed regular expressions that each match a single-character string.

I assume the user enters RETURN to signal that no more characters are to be entered. The user is to be permitted to enter RETURN only when the previous entry was a digit.

1. Define `r = /[-\d]/`.
2. The first character entered must match `r`.
3. If the first character entered is `'-'`, set `r = /\d/`, else (as the first character was a digit) set `r = /[\d.]/`.
4. If the previous character was a period update `r = /\d/` and require the user to enter a character that matches `r` (i.e, a digit); else the user may press RETURN or enter a character that matches `r` (which could be `/\d/` or `/[\d.]/`).
5. Repeat step 4 until the user presses RETURN.

Note that, in step 4, once `r` is set `/\d/` it remains at that value until the user presses RETURN.

If a user entry (including RETURN) is rejected it would be helpful to display a message giving the reason for it being rejected.